# Can an EC2 instance resolve the DNS of my other EC2 instances in the same region?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2

I have multiple EC2 instances in the same availability zone that need to connect with each other. Will the public DNS of each instance be able to resolve without any extra configuration?

Comment: Yes. It will, based on the AWS EC2 default host names it assigns to you when you spin up one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, and as a bonus, Amazon will return the internal IPs rather than the external ones so you benefit from cheaper internal traffic.

Comment: When I ping or telnet a DNS of the other instances in the same zone, I do not get a response

Comment: Amazon's security groups block ICMP (which includes ping) by default, and you'll only be able to telnet to ports that've been opened to your instance in the destination's security group.

Comment: I fixed this by adding the security group to itself

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.